# Comparing times within two vectores and finding nearest for each element in R

Tags: r, datetime, for-loop

I have a problem going out of basic programming towards more sophisticated. Could you help me to adjust this code?

There are two vectors with dates and times, one is when activities happens, and another one - when triggers appear. The aim is to find nearest activities date/time to each of triggers, after each trigger happen. Final result is average of all differences.

I have this code. It works. But it's very slow when working with large dataset.

```
time_activities<- as.POSIXct(c("2008-09-14 22:15:14","2008-09-15 09:05:14","2008-09-16 14:05:14","2008-09-17 12:05:14"), , "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
time_triggers<- as.POSIXct(c("2008-09-15 06:05:14","2008-09-17 12:05:13"), , "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
for (j in 1:length(time_triggers))
{
  for(i in 1:length(time_activities))
  {
    if(time_triggers[j]<time_activities[i])
    {
      result[j] = ceiling(difftime(time_activities[i], time_triggers[j], units = 'mins'))
      break
    }
  }
}
print(mean(as.numeric(result)))
```

Can I somehow get rid of the loop, and do everything with vectors? Maybe you can give me some hint of which function I could use to compare dates at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
delay=sapply(time_triggers,function(x) max(subset(difftime(x,time_activities,units='mins'),difftime(x,time_activities,units='mins')<0)))
mean(delay[is.finite(delay)])
```

This should do the trick. As always, the `apply` family of functions is a good replacement for a `for` loop.

This gives the average number of minutes that an activity occurred after a trigger.

If you want to see what the activity delay was after each trigger (rather than just the mean of all the triggers), you can just remove the `mean()` at the beginning. The values will then correspond to each value in `time_triggers`.

UPDATE:
I updated the code to ignore `Inf` values as requested. Sadly, this means the code should be 2 lines rather than 1. If you really want, you can make this all one line, but then you will be doing the majority of the computation twice (not very efficient).

Comment: Hi, thank you very much. Worked very well, and fast :) Only there were one issue. If after "trigger" no "activity" happened results was equal to inf. Thus that needs to be checked before calculating mean.

Comment: Updated as per your request!

Comment: Thank you again, looks very nice